# pyobj access to iTunes application

Tags: python, macos, applescript, itunes, pyobjc

Let's say I managed to get the dictionary opened for iTunes in the Applescript editor:

[image]

How would I access the "search" commands using Python with pyobjc?

I know I get can hold of the iTunes application using:

`iTunes = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")`

but after I do a `dir` on it, I don't see the *search* command in the returned dictionary. Help please!

Comment: Its worth noting that in many cases, `dir` will not give you a complete list of valid object attribute references. Many Python classes (especially wrappers) will implement the `__getattr__` method. In short, it means that an object can have "attributes" that are not explicitly defined, and these don't automatically make themselves apparent in a call to `dir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) instead of Scripting Bridge.  There are versions available for Python, Ruby and Objective-C.  Unlike Scripting Bridge, appscript is designed to work with Apple Events rather than make it pretend to be something it isn't; it's also quite a bit more flexible and less buggy.  As a bonus, you don't have to go through PyObjC.

The appscript documentation is good and worth reading.  You can install [ASTranslate](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/tools.html) which will convert an AppleScript script into appscript code for any of the above languages.  When I'm doing something tricky, I often write it in (Apple)Script Editor, then convert into Python with ASTranslate.  There's also ASDictionary, which produces HTML-formatted versions of dictionaries formatted for appscript languages; I don't use it much since I find experimenting with Script Editor more accessible.  (However, if you don't have much experience with AppleScript, maybe it'd be a better choice.)

For some examples of controlling iTunes with Python appscript, you can see [some](http://dev.sabi.net/trac/dev/browser/trunk/Update%20Podcasts/update_podcasts.py) [scripts](http://dev.sabi.net/trac/dev/browser/trunk/StreamVision/StreamVision.py) I wrote.

Comment: appscript is no longer recommended to be used.